# Gem install ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I'm new to sass/compass, and I'd like to know how is the first statement (below) different from the second one.

1. `compass install compass;`
2. `gem install compass`

I also need to know whether I should use the second statement every time I create a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the difference between the 2(heck i didn't even know the first one was an option). But my advice would be to add gems in the gemfile and run bundle install.

**2 reasons:**

**1:** *Options:* when you do `gem install compass` it installs the gem automatically for your whole environment. And in your gemfile you can seperate it over different groups.

**2:** *Readability* : If you use **gem install compass** the gem will not be visible in your gemfile, so when other people try to work on your project they can't see all the gems used in the application through the gemfile (annoying).

Comment: ummm... ok, call me an idiot, but what is a gemfile :-) ? Also can I install compass in an existing project by navigating to the directory and typing compass install (as opposed to compass install [project name]) ?

Comment: In your rails folder you have an gemfile.rb file if you open it you can put: gem 'compass-rails' in there and run 'bundle install' in your terminal to install the gem.

Comment: You can check this link:  https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails for more info about the compass-rails gem and how to use it.